Does this proposition hold? Let $G$ be a group and $H$,$K$ subgroups of G. If $HK \subseteq KH$, then $HK = KH$?
I found the following proposition in this page of Groupprops.
Two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a group $G$ are termed permuting subgroups if the following equivalent conditions hold:

$HK = KH$;
$HK$ is a subgroup of G;
$HK \subseteq KH$;
$\left[ H,K \right] \subseteq HK$.

The equivalence of conditions 1 and 2 is well known. But I don't know how to prove the rest. The full proof in Groupprops is empty, and the References is useless，
It is easy to see that we can derive $KH \subseteq HK$ from condition 4, so it's sufficed to prove that 3 $\Rightarrow$ 1. However, I think condition 3 is too weak and I can't get  useful information from that.
I apologize for my poor English.

Can't you prove directly that $KH$ is a subgroup from (3)?

(3) implies that $KH$ is closed under inverses, and products: $(k_1h_1)(k_2h_2) = k_1(h_1k_2)h_2\in K(HK)H \subseteq KKHH = KH$.

Your English is far from poor.

@ArturoMagidin Thank you very much! I made a low-level mistake...

@ArturoMagidin Yes but we want that $HK$ is a subgroup. So a small step is missing. But there is a more direct way (see my answer).

@MartinBrandenburg: I'm proving $KH$ is a subgroup, which given the equivalence of 1 and 2 that is being described as "well known", is the same thing. There is no step missing, I'm just not doing the same thing you are doing.

Yes this is the small step that I meant (the equivalence between 1 and 2, and that 1 is symmetric).

If $HK \subseteq KH$, then $KH=K^{-1} H^{-1} = (HK)^{-1} \subseteq (KH)^{-1} = H^{-1} K^{-1} = HK$.

To my surprise, I haven't seen this argument in the related questions posted on this site (those about checking when $HK$ is a subgroup). But maybe I am missing something.
